# I bought an album yesterday with 22 tracks on it, but only 10 show up for download

Tags: ubuntu-one

All 22 show up in the download queue within Rhythmbox. The queuing feature never really works there anyway though, so I usually go to the web site, click on Files/Purchased Music/band/track to get what I purchased.

This has worked well for other albums, but 'Greatest Hit ... (and 21 other pretty cool songs) has been showing 10 tracks for the past 17 hours. Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues with Rythmbox, It has to do something with the "tags" of the tracks. To make my mp3's shown under the corresponding Album and not scattered around, I had to fix those files with a program called EasyTags.
Ultimately, I had to switch to Banshee Media Player...

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the files are on your desktop and are either not getting picked up or getting picked up in a weird way by Rhythmbox; check your `~/.ubuntuone/Purchased from Ubuntu One/` folder.

If the songs are *not* in that folder, please check [the same folder via the web interface](https://one.ubuntu.com/files/u/~/.ubuntuone/Purchased%20from%20Ubuntu%20One).

If the songs are not online either, please [contact support](https://one.ubuntu.com/support/contact/).